# Polymer 1.0 wildcard bind against a nested subproperty in an array

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0, observers, computed-properties

Say I have a data object like so:

```
const o = [
  {name: "A", v: 1, other: 0},
  {name: "B", v: 7, other: 0},
  {name: "C", v: 8, other: 0},
  {name: "D", v: 1, other: 1},
]
```

I want to be able to define a nested observer like:

```
_sumOfVs(o.*.v)
```

This way the observer only updates when the `v` key in the objects are edited, and not recomputed when `name` or `other` are updated. Currently the best I can do is to define the observer as `_sumsOfVs(o.*)`:

```
_sumsOfVs = obj => obj.base.reduce((p,c) => p+c.v, 0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to observe only specific subproperties off a wildcard (`o.*.v`), but you could check the change-record's path in the wildcard observer (`o.*`), filtering out unwanted paths so that the observer exits early if the change-record does not apply to `.v`.

```
_sumOfVs: function(changeRecord) {
  if (changeRecord.path.endsWith('.v')) {
    const sum = changeRecord.base.reduce((p,c) => p + Number(c.v), 0);
    console.log('sum', sum);
  }
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mrYoaG?editors=1011)